# Mysql limit on the no of users?

Tags: mysql, user-management

We are planning migrate most of our authentication system from within our application to mysql. How many no. of user can mysql handle? I am talking about a couple of thousands at the moment and perhaps a lot more in the future. Am highly apprehensive about doing this, but couldn't find anything more than, if it isn't said , it is unlimited type of answers.

I am worried about the number of users mysql can manage.

I know about the max_connections variable and memory limit, which is a key factor for that.

Comment: Please clarify if you need information about how many user connections a mySQL server may handle, or if there is a maximum number of users which mysql can manage?

Comment: @pacey: it is the max number of users mysql can manage. i am guessing, but is it really the same problem as managing max records in a table??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a powerful server, you can expect performance about 10000 tps to read and 6000 tps to write(DB about 20Gb with 50 million rows). Also you can use memcached to cache and read-only replica and sharding.